# Can VS Code split view "lock" the cursor on the same split when going Back and forth?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Sometime I use VS code to split the same file left and right,
like keeping the left split on the general code flow while using the right split to navigate the APIs written on the same file(i.e. file1.c on both left and right split)

After I review the definition of an API (e.g. @Line 100) from another source file (e.g. file2.c), which mostly open on the right split, I use my mouse's macro key for a "Go Back" action, same as pressing "ALT+Left"

But everytime the cursor will not go back to the Line 100 in the right split of file1.c (where I press F12), but instead jump to the line100 in the left view.

Is there any setting I can change so when I press "ALT+Left", it can jump bank to the Line 100 in the right split?

Comment: Will just `Cursor Undo` ctrl+U work for you?

Comment: @Mark No, It seems on the cursor return to the first line of the secondary file.

Answer (score 0):

See the `Navigation Scope` option in the `Workbench`->`Editor` section of Settings. Setting it to `editorGroup` or `editor` restricts the cursor navigation to the history of the current editor group or the current editor, respectively.